# input text fill up remaining space

Tags: html, css

I've been looking around for like an hour or so now. And I cant seem to find out what I have to do.
What I want to make is a login form. I want the span and the input next to each other. Where the input has to fill the whole size.
This is my code:

```
<div id="login_div">

<form>

    <ul id="login_nav">
        <li>
            <span class="login_span">Username</span>
            <input class="login_input" type="text" name="username" />

        </li>

        <li>
            <span class="login_span">Password</span>
            <input class="login_input" type="password" name="password"/>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </li>

    </ul>

</form>
```

The `<li>` has to be the full width of the `login_div`, lets say 500px. The span has a certain width, lets say 100px. Then I want the input to get the remaining space.
I want to achieve this all without hardcoding the width.

Any ideas?

Comment: just a tip... keep this html semantic! use labels and not spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `float` and layout propeties. wrapping your `input` in an element.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/edABK)**

---

Your `span` should be a `label`, and if `input` is wrapped in a `span` you can have the `label` floatting.

The `span` (or else tag) aside can use all space left avalaible ** if layout is triggered so it care about floatting element**.

At this  point , you just have to set `width: 100%` to `input` to fill up all space remaining:

```
<div id="login_div">
<form>
    <ul id="login_nav">
        <li>
            <label class="login_span">Username</label>
            <span class="login_span"><input class="login_input" type="text" name="username" /></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="login_span">Password</label>
            <span class="login_span"><input class="login_input" type="password" name="password"/></span>
        </li>
        <li>          
               <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </li>

    </ul>
</form>
```

and basic CSS:l

```
label{
  float:left;
  width:100px;/* option, whatever */
  }
span {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;/* triggers layout, so doesnt show beneath float element */
  margin-right:1em;/* option, whatever */
}
span input {
  width:100%;/* use all space avalaible */
  box-sizing:border-box;/* use prefix where needed */
}
```

Comment: no matter width of form , as long it's wide enough to hold label and span aside each other on th line.

Comment: A very good answer, I already had problems with box-sizing, but never know how to solve it, and by testing your solution I learned more one "tip" of css... thanks.

Comment: @Jacobi glad this was usefull to you too

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CSS3 calc function?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

```
.login_span {width:100px; display:inline-block; }
.login_input {width:calc(100% - 120px); display:inline-block;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bW3ak/

Answer (score -1):

To do it without hardcoding a width:

```
#login_nav li { display: table; width: 100%; }
#login_nav li span,
#login_nav li input { display: table-cell; }
```